# When i try to scrape web table text values using selenium xpath it gives empty text values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get text values from the below URL Annual & quarterly tables. but it gives empty value. what might be the problem here. can anyone give me some help?
These are the values I'm trying to extract,

[image]

This is the code : in this, I'm trying to get 2018 text. i need all of the text inside the box.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
import os

url = f'https://www.morningstar.ca/ca/report/stocks/financials.aspx?t=0P000000GY&lang=en-CA'

codePath = os.getcwd() + r"\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver"
PATH = os.path.join(codePath)
service = Service(PATH)

service.start()
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# option.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, options=option)

driver.get(url);
time.sleep(2) 

Y1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/sal-components/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/th[2]/span')[0].text
print(Y1)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what you're trying to do but to get table text value just need to do the following:

Assuming that your code snippet works fine and the problem is just with Y1, you can do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
import os

url = f'https://www.morningstar.ca/ca/report/stocks/financials.aspx?t=0P000000GY&lang=en-CA'

codePath = os.getcwd() + r"\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver"
PATH = os.path.join(codePath)
service = Service(PATH)

service.start()
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# option.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, options=option)

driver.get(url);
time.sleep(2) 

Y1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='report-table ng-isolate-scope']")))

print(Y1.text)

driver.close()
```

Is it necessary to use WebDriverWait? The answer is no, i did it with WebDriverWait because you imported it and it was not being used.

The above code prints table text value:

```
Fiscal 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 TTM 5-Yr Index
103.40
Return on Assets % 27.07 28.54 19.34 18.01 20.45 14.93 13.87 16.07 15.69 17.33 23.21 16.19 7.11
Return on Equity % 41.67 42.84 30.64 33.61 46.25 36.90 36.87 49.36 55.92 73.69 103.40 51.97 22.62
Return on Invested Capital % 41.04 42.01 26.08 26.20 31.32 21.95 19.86 24.41 25.75 30.11 40.07 24.98 12.64
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, It works fine with this table class, but this is not the table I'm trying to get text value. so I change class name to "//table[@class='sal-summary-section__table']" but not work.

Comment: what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong locator.
Also you have to use expected conditions to wait until the element is loaded. I see it sometimes takes a long time here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
import os

url = f'https://www.morningstar.ca/ca/report/stocks/financials.aspx?t=0P000000GY&lang=en-CA'

codePath = os.getcwd() + r"\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver"
PATH = os.path.join(codePath)
service = Service(PATH)

service.start()
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# option.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, options=option)

driver.get(url);

Y1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='sal-components-scrollable ng-isolate-scope'])[1]")))

print(Y1.text)

driver.close()
```

Comment: In the URL, You can see `table value something like that`, btw I used this xpath : `//span[text()='TTM']/../../following-sibling::tr/td[@ng-repeat]`

Comment: The locator I used here is unique will what you pasted here selects 20 items

Comment: Well, that's exactly he wants to extract from web page right ?

Comment: As far as I understand